# Kafka aggregate single log event lines to a combined log event

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I'm using Kafka to process log events. I have basic knowledge of Kafka Connect and Kafka Streams for simple connectors and stream transformations.

Now I have a log file with the following structure:

```
timestamp event_id event
```

A log event has multiple log lines which are connected by the event_id (for example a mail log)

Example:

```
1234 1 START
1235 1 INFO1
1236 1 INFO2
1237 1 END
```

And in general there are multiple events:

Example:

```
1234 1 START
1234 2 START
1235 1 INFO1
1236 1 INFO2
1236 2 INFO3
1237 1 END
1237 2 END
```

The time window (between START and END) could be up to 5 minutes.

As result I want a topic like

```
event_id combined_log
```

Example:

```
1 START,INFO1,INFO2,END
2 START,INFO2,END
```

What are the right tools to achieve this? I tried to solve it with Kafka Streams but I can figure out how..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your use case you are essentially reconstructing sessions or transactions based on message payloads.  At the moment there is no built-in, ready-to-use support for such functionality.  However, you can use the Processor API part of Kafka's Streams API to implement this functionality yourself.  You can write custom processors that use a state store to track when, for a given key, a session/transaction is STARTed, added to, and ENDed.

Some users in the mailing lists have been doing that IIRC, though I am not aware of an existing code example that I could point you to.

What you need to watch out for is to properly handle out-of-order data.  In your example above you listed all input data in proper order:

```
1234 1 START
1234 2 START
1235 1 INFO1
1236 1 INFO2
1236 2 INFO3
1237 1 END
1237 2 END
```

In practice though, messages/records may arrive out-of-order, like so (I only show messages with key `1` to simplify the example):

```
1234 1 START
1237 1 END
1236 1 INFO2
1235 1 INFO1
```

Even if that happens, I understand that in your use case you still want to interpret this data as: `START -> INFO1 -> INFO2 -> END` rather than `START -> END` (ignoring/dropping `INFO1` and `INFO2` = data loss) or `START -> END -> INFO2 -> INFO1` (incorrect order, probably also violating your semantic constraints).

Comment: Thanks for the answer I will take a look on the Processor API. Yes also the order problem should be considered.

Comment: @imehl: Perhaps you want to update your question above with some info on what you actually ended up doing to solve your problem, now that you found a solution?